# Weird grammar on the moderator flag dashboard

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, grammar

I noticed that the /admin/dashboard page has some weird grammar:

> #### Where should I start?
>
> Start at the top. This list is ordered by a combination of number (and type) of issues, the reputation of the user who posted, and the flag history and reputation of the flagging user.

This sounds kind of awkward; it reads as "a combination of number, ..., ..." which makes it sound like there's some sort of "flag number" or something. "The reputation of the user who posted" also sounds a bit odd, like there's a way to "post a flag."

Could it be changed to something like this?

> This list is ordered by a combination of amount and type of issues, the reputation of the flagged post's owner, and the flag history and reputation of the flagging user.

Or, even better:

> This list is ordered by a combination of:
>
> - the amount and type of issues
> - the reputation of the flagged post's owner
> - the flag history and reputation of the flagging user

Comment: All of that is a lie anyways. It's sorted by number of flags on the post and then by time of the oldest flag. There might as well be a picture of cake over in that sidebar...

Comment: @animuson Wait, it is? How do you know?

Comment: Those were the sorting parameters way back when flag weight used to exist. Stack Overflow has a massive flags queue. It's pretty easy to figure out how it's being sorted.

Comment: It does feel like sorting stones sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

The statement reads perfectly grammatically to me, a native English (well, Scottish, but with a strong Received Pronunciation streak) speaker.

Your suggestion to use *amount* doesn't read as well, as *number* is the **most** correct use of language here.

I think your use of *flagged post's owner* does work better than the original.

Your list-based suggestion is actually the most useful, as it removes the problem of misunderstanding (although as @animuson suggests - the question is largely irrelevant anyway :-) )

Comment: Yeah, "amount" is, at best, awkward in there. (Says this non-native speaker.) But the rest looks fine to me. We could also likely improve things a ways by using an article in front of "number" and removing the parentheses around "(and  type) in the existing copy.